# How disable caching for images in one folder, but enable for all other folders

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I have structure

```
/media
    images
        file1_dis.jpg
        file2_dis.jpg
        .... 
        other_images
           subfolders
               file1_en.jpg
               file2_en.jpg
```

I want enable caching for all files in subfolders, but disable caching for files in folder `/media/images`

Structure of site i cant't change.

Now i have code in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 3015 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

its enable caching for all images on my site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You should put .htaccess with code

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 3015 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

in folder other_images

2) You can use directive [DirectoryMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directorymatch)

Comment: Note that Note that while <Files> and <FilesMatch> work in .htaccess, the directives <Directory>, <DirectoryMatch> and <Location> only work at the server config level.

Answer (score 5):

insert a file into the subfolder with content you want NOT CACHE as follows

file name

.htaccess

contents of this file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# disable caching forthis directory mod_expires for this directory
ExpiresActive off
</IfModule>
```

For detailed information: http://static.askapache.com/httpd/modules/mod_expires.c

For MORE detail information: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html#mod_expires_Caching_EX-_1